# How to optimize the following query?

Tags: sql

I have two tables: maskedindextable and dictionarytable.

The dictionarytable has four columns:

```
ID (primary key)
filelocation
dictionaryEncryptedIndex
dictionaryEncryptedWord
```

and values look like this:

```
ID | filelocation | dictionaryencryptedindex | dictionaryEncryptedWord
0 | c:/test.txt | 0x01 | EAD64zef6z
1 | c:/test.txt | 0x02 | 5ez4f
2 | c:/test.txt | 0x03 | ze654f
3 | c:/john.txt | 0x01 | 6ze5f4
4 | c:/john.txt | 0x02 | ze5f68z4f
5 | c:/john.txt | 0x03 | EAD64zef6z 
6 | c:/smith.txt | 0x01  | er6g4
7 | c:/smith.txt | 0x02 | z6e58g4
8 | c:/smith.txt | 0x03  | a64zef6z
9 | c:/laura.txt | 0x01  | EAD64zef6z
```

This table has 700 000 values

The maskedindextable has four columns:

```
ID (primary key)
filelocation
maskedIndexEncryptedIndex
maskedIndexEncryptedValue
```

values look like this:

```
ID | filelocation | maskedIndexEncryptedIndex | maskedIndexEncryptedValue
0 | c:/test.txt | 0x01 | 5z1ef
1 | c:/test.txt | 0x02 | e6rh546er4g
2 | c:/test.txt | 0x03 | z6ef548ezf
3 | c:/john.txt | 0x01 | (y48try68
4 | c:/john.txt | 0x02 | iu47k
5 | c:/john.txt | 0x03 | 6tkj
6 | c:/smith.txt | 0x01  | 6ez5r48
7 | c:/smith.txt | 0x02 | 6i5
8 | c:/smith.txt | 0x03  | 6e5rg
9 | c:/laura.txt | 0x01  | ze654f
```

This table also has 700 000 values

The dictionaryencryptedindex & filelocation combination in table dictionarytable corresponds with the maskedIndexEncryptedIndex & filelocation in table maskedindextable .
I want to find the corresponding maskedindexencryptedvalue, for which the encrypted words are EAD64zef6z. Currently I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MaskedIndexTable.filelocation, 
       dictionaryencryptedindex,
       maskedindexencryptedvalue
FROM MaskedIndexTable 
INNER JOIN DictionaryTable 
        ON MaskedIndexTable.maskedIndexEncryptedIndex = 
           DictionaryTable.dictionaryEncryptedIndex  
WHERE MaskedIndexTable.Id IN  
(SELECT DictionaryTable.Id 
 FROM  DictionaryTable 
 WHERE  `dictionaryEncryptedWord` LIKE 'EAD64zef6z') 
 AND  `dictionaryEncryptedWord` LIKE 'EAD64zef6z';
```

But this query runs terribly slow (takes 3 seconds). Does anyone know how I can optimize my query?

Comment: indexing, as per Marjeta's answer is proabably the best bet.  Also, in the every little bit helps department, you are using LIKE without a wildcard.  Using = might gain you a nanosecond or two.

Comment: Most database engines provide a way of inspecting the query plan to determine which part of a query is causing performance problems (such as missing indices).  Though in this case, I suspect it's your sub-select, not a missing index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the simpler statement

```
SELECT dt.filelocation, dictionaryencryptedindex, maskedindexencryptedvalue
FROM MaskedIndexTable mit
INNER JOIN DictionaryTable  dt
  ON mit.maskedIndexEncryptedIndex = dt.dictionaryEncryptedIndex
  AND mit.filelocation = dt.filelocation 
WHERE dt.dictionaryEncryptedWord = 'EAD64zef6z';
```

You don't need a `LIKE` if you're not using wildcards. Also you can add multiple conditions in the `ON` Clause of a `JOIN`  Statement.

You will need indexes on the WHERE and JOIN columns, i.e. `DictionaryTable.dictionaryEncryptedWord`, `DictionaryTable.filelocation`, `DictionaryTable.dictionaryEncryptedIndex`, `MaskedIndexTable.filelocation`, and `MaskedIndexTable.maskedIndexEncryptedIndex`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this works perfectly and is a huge improvement.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, whenever a query is slow, it turns out that a column mentioned in WHERE clause doesn't have an index.

Try indexing all the columns appearing in WHERE clauses.

Comment: If you need help creating INDEXES you can start here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, the sub-select in your WHERE clause seems to serve no purpose.  You are also using `LIKE` instead of a simple `=`.  Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MIT.filelocation, 
   dictionaryencryptedindex,
   maskedindexencryptedvalue
FROM MaskedIndexTable MIT
    INNER JOIN DictionaryTable DT
    ON MIT.maskedIndexEncryptedIndex = 
       DT.dictionaryEncryptedIndex  
WHERE dictionaryEncryptedWord = 'EAD64zef6z';
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the select in where clausure

```
SELECT DISTINCT MaskedIndexTable.filelocation, dictionaryencryptedindex
,     maskedindexencryptedvalue

FROM MaskedIndexTable INNER JOIN DictionaryTable ON MaskedIndexTable.maskedIndexEncryptedIndex = DictionaryTable.dictionaryEncryptedIndex  
WHERE `dictionaryEncryptedWord` LIKE 'EAD64zef6z';
```